# PHP - Insert data into MySQL table with 2 foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a school project - a website with students performances in various sports. I have three tables:

**TABLE1 - "students"**

- id (primary key)
- class
- firstname
- lastname

**TABLE2 - "sports"**

- sport_id (primary key)
- sportname

**TABLE3 - "performances"**

- performance_id (primary key)
- sport_id (foreign key - sports.sport_id)
- student_id (foreign key - students.id)
- value

I want to make a form that adds data into the third table. 
That form should include:

- class
- firstname
- lastname
- sportname
- value

...but I have no idea how to achieve this.

I could just create a form where user user adds value and then copy-pastes sport_id and student_id from tables below it, but that's unpractical.

I've been searching the internet for a while, but I haven't found any solution to this and if I did, it was only for one foreign key.

Does anyone know how to do this? If so, I would highly appreciate it! :)

EDIT: I should've mentioned that tables "students" and "sports" already have all the data in them, I just need to insert new performances using that data.

Comment: what have you got working so far?

Comment: do an insert in first table - you'll get the new id back with [last_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), same for 2nd table, then use both ids to insert into 3rd table. (or fetch the sports.id via a dropdown if it exists already)

Comment: I have a working form that just has sport_id, student_id and value + a table that shows all required data from tables `SELECT * FROM performances
INNER JOIN sports ON sports.sport_id = performances.sport_id
INNER JOIN students ON students.id = performances.student_id`

Comment: I should've mentioned that tables "students" and "sports" already have all the data in them, I just need to insert new performances using that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is already in the tables for students and sports, this information can be queried with some `select` statements in order to populate some HTML dropdowns.  The advantage of using the select queries and the dropdowns is that `value` of the options can be set to the database ID while showing the user the human-readable text.  Then, the page just needs to monitor for the form's submission and insert the IDs from the dropdowns along with the performance metric.  I have not tested the code below, but here is a quicky example of how that might work.

Note:  I like the [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) interface for preparing SQL queries in order to prevent injection attacks.

```
<?php
$user = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$con = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1;chartset=urf8', $user, $password);

$student_stmt = $con->prepare('select * from students');
$student_stmt->execute();

$sport_stmt = $con->prepare('select * from sports');
$sport_stmt->execute();

if (isset($_GET['student']) && isset($_GET['sport']) && isset($_GET['value'])) {
    $student = $_GET['student'];
    $sport = $_GET['sport'];
    $value = $_GET['value'];
    $insert_stmt = $con->prepare('insert into preformances (sport_id, student_id, value) values (:sport_id, :student_id, :value)');
    $insert_stmt->bindParam(':sport_id', $sport);
    $insert_stmt->bindParam(':student_id', $student);
    $insert_stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
    $insert_stmt->execute();
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="self.php" method="get">
            Student:
            <select name="student">
    <?php while ($row = $student_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
            </select>

            Sport:
            <select name="sport">
    <?php while ($row = $sport_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['sport_id']; ?>"><?php echo "$row['sportname']"; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
            </select>
            Performance: <input name="value" type="text" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
Made the changes in the code in the suggested comment.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it working with few changes - I hope it helps others too!


1. I added `charset=utf8`to `$con` so characters like "č" or "ř" display properly  

2. replaced `($_GET['student']` with `(isset($_GET['student'])`  

3. replaced `$row['student_id']` with `$row['id']`

Comment: Thanks!  made the updates to the code.  It's been a while since I used PHP, so I completely forgot about the isset() function :)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to get input values from your form (`$variable = $_GET["classinput"];`) and then connect to database and write mysqli query with input query for every table.

like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO STUDENTS(id,class,firstname,lastname) VALUES (null,\"$class\",\"$firstname\",\"$lastname\")");
```

And do this for all your tables.

Comment: I should've mentioned that tables "students" and "sports" already have all the data in them, I just need to insert new performances using that data